# Laravel Notification Class is looking thru Class 'App\Http\Controllers

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

I made a notification on Laravel by:

```
php artisan notifications:table
php artisan migrate
php artisan make:notification TestNotificationUpdate
```

The table and class are created fine.

When I use the notification like:

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //---- SOME CODE VALIDATION HERE ---- 

    //For testing..
    //Notifying my self
    auth()->user()->notify( new TestNotificationUpdate() );

    //---- SOME CODE STORE DB HERE ---- 
    //---- REDIRECT ---- 
}
```

Im getting the error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Class 'App\Http\Controllers\TestNotificationUpdate' not
>   found

Of course, the notification class is on `App\Http\**Notifications**\`. I am not sure what I'm missing. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try  `php artisan config:cache`  `php artisan config:clear`  `composer dump-autoload -o`

Comment: You need to add a use statement at the top of your controller ```use App\Http\Notifications\TestNotificationUpdate```

Comment: Do you have a `use` clause at the top of your file?

Comment: Ohh... I added `use App\Http\Notifications\TestNotificationUpdate;` and getting.`Class 'App\Http\Notifications\TestNotificationUpdate' not found`..

Comment: I added `use App\Notifications\TestNotificationUpdate;` and works fine now. Thanks alot guys. :)